# create initrd image compressed with zstd

Tags: kernel, boot, initrd, zstd

I have initrd image compressed with `xz`. This is how I created it from image file `initrd`:

```
e2image -ar initrd - | xz -9 --check=crc32 > initrd.xz
```

now I need same image compressed using `zstd` algorithm. What command/parameters do I have to use, for the kernel to be able boot from this initrd image?

I have `CONFIG_RD_ZSTD=y` enabled in my kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent with `zstd` shall be :

`e2image -ar initrd - | zstd -19 --check > initrd.zst`